# /subscribers/{imsi}/set_expiry_time で New expiry date is before the current time が発生する

Tags: soracom

/subscribers/{imsi}/set_expiry_time を以下の条件で実行したときに New expiry date is before the current time が発生します。パラメータの指定が悪いのでしょうか？
※APIは、https://dev.soracom.io/jp/docs/api/ から確認しております。

URL: /subscribers/{imsi}/set_expiry_time
json:

```
{
  "expiryTime": 1446336000 // 2015-11-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
}
```

Response Body

```
{
  "code": "SEM0006",
  "message": "New expiry date is before the current time"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expiryTimeの指定はミリ秒単位となります。
そのため、2015-11-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC は 1446336000000 を指定下さい。

APIドキュメントにもミリ秒単位である旨、記載させていただきます。

Comment: ありがとうございました。1446336000000に値を変更したら、正常に値を更新することができました。

Comment: [APIドキュメント](https://dev.soracom.io/jp/docs/api/#!/Subscriber/set_expiry_time_subscriber)も更新しました